# What was this TV movie featuring Peter Ustinov and a space ship?

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

In the late 70’s (possibly early 80’s) there was a much hyped multi-part TV movie that was supposed to be a murder mystery. There was a contest where people would write in with their solution before the final part aired.

It opened with <strike>Peter Ustinov</strike> dressed in Russian-style winder coat and hat, riding an escalator. Now I can't find anything like this under Peter Ustinov in IMDB so I might be remembering the name wrong.

It was about a murder on a spaceship traveling home from Mars, I think.  One so-called clue was a white scarf.

Does anybody know what movie this was?

Comment: Are you sure that it is about a murder on a spaceship?  Peter Ustinov starred in a series of TV Movies in the late seventies, early eighties as the character Hercule Poirot based on Agatha Christie mystery novels.

Comment: The one I'm thinking of was *not* Poirot.  It was definitely on a space ship.

Comment: Sounds similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treasure_Island_in_Outer_Space

Comment: No, it was not Treasure Island.  It was a murder mystery, with a viewer contest to guess the perpetrator.

Comment: Man, I was willing to swear that _[The Mouse On The Moon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057328/)_ had Peter Ustinov in it. Oh well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The movie is called *Murder in Space* from 1985.  It does not star Peter Ustinov.  It stars Wilford Brimley, who can easily be mistaken as Peter Ustinov.  It aired as a Science Fiction Murder [Mystery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_in_Space).

> Murder in Space is a 1985 science fiction murder mystery movie set in
>   the near future. The crew of an international space mission are on the
>   **return leg from Mars to Earth** when an explosion occurs on the craft
>   Conestoga, shortly after a series of murders starts. The crew of the
>   returning craft are forbidden to return until the murderer is caught.
>
> On its initial premier, the film was shown without the ending and a
>   competition was set for the **viewers to solve the mystery** of who the
>   murderer or murderers were. The conclusion of the film was shown
>   several days later, with the contestants eliminated one by one until
>   the winner correctly identified the killer or killers. The final 30
>   minutes of the film was shown at a later date when the mystery was
>   solved.

Comment: Wilford Brimley easily mistaken as Peter Ustinov!? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uHBFiAnpZs

Comment: @faintsignal Wut?  Look at pics of them from 1985...Ustinov even has the moustache.  It's not as apparent as Brimley's moustache, but...they both look like fat, bearded old men ;)  Nice Lombard retort, btw ;)